# Possible problem with Video Ads & Stuck partial wake locks (background)

Tags: android, wakelock, android-vitals

We have had an issue with Android Vitals for some time. It's about *Stuck partial wake locks (background)*. We are not able to find out why we face *bad behaviour* here because we always use the foreground service that plays sound (our application is a audio app). The problem mainly affects Huawei and Oppo devices.

We run a test recently, turned off the video ads, then waited a few days. It seems that evidently, after excluding this type of advertising, the indicator dropped by ~50% (from 0.20% of sessions to 0.9%) in the first days only.

We have experienced the same problem for many months now. We use AdMob Mediation (AdMob, Facebook, AppLovin, MoPub) and bidding for several months. The problem has been around for a long time, no matter what version of the libraries is used.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and would help us?

Comment: Have similar problem